# My android stuck with page in Chinese

Tags: boot, htc-desire-816-dual

My device is a *HTC desire 816* dual sim, and now the Android system is stuck on a form with Chinese language. Even after I performed a factory-reset it is still stuck with the same screen.

So what does it need to get back to normal factory setting?

[image: Chinese screen] [image: errors in recovery]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>